# runOnChange=false but change in csv gave checksum error

Tags: java, sql, liquibase

We had this changeset as shown below. We load data from csv file. Liquibase script was executed. Then somebody changed myfile.csv file i.e. updated some data in existing row. So we got following error:

> DMLChangeLog.xml::124::mp is now:
>   7:33820845173c612453bd2e3441398011

```
<changeSet author="mp" id="124" runOnChange="false">
    <loadData encoding="UTF-8" file="myfile.csv" tableName="tbl_sysparam">
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

I understand this is due to change is csv. But I'm not able to understand why so? What is the point of putting runOnChange="false" then?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to re-load this data any time it changes, then you would set `runOnChange` to true. When it is set to false, Liquibase protects the database against changes. However, you would need to protect the database from duplication, etc., so the changeset would need to be designed such that it can be re-run successfully.

Normally, you don't want the same changeset to run twice on a database. If you have a changeset that creates a table, you don't want that changeset to run again because it would fail. This is also true for a changeset that inserts data - if you have already inserted data, you don't want to re-insert all the data if just one row has changed. If you want to change one row, you should write a changeset that deletes that one row and then inserts the new data.

The `runOnChange` attribute is typically used for things like stored procedures where you have a `CREATE OR UPDATE` style of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`runOnChange="false"`
specifies default behavior: fail on any change of changeset.

`runOnChange="true"`
causes rerun on change without error.

You can use `failOnError=false` to just suppress error in your case.